# how do i loop a viewbag list of address in javascript mvc

Tags: c#

on my controller i have a list of addresses that i would like to pass to the view so i have the foolowing code that only processes one record but does not loop through each record

```
<script>
    function initMap() {

        var uluru = { lat: @ViewBag.Latitude, lng: @ViewBag.Longitude };
    //var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: uluru,
        // Set mapTypeId to SATELLITE in order
        // to activate satellite imagery.
        mapTypeId: 'satellite',
        zoom: 8
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've assigned a List to the ViewBag

```
ViewBag.Addresses = new List<Address>() { ... };
```

One way is to use a for loop to push into a JavaScript array.

```
<script>
    var coordinates = [];

@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Addresses.Count(); i++)
{
    <text>
    coordinates.push({lat: @ViewBag.Addresses[i].Latitude, lng: @ViewBag.Addresses[i].Longitude });
    </text>
}

   var map ...
</script>
```

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GeoPortal.Farm>.Count' cannot be used like a method.